# Create a single Table from Get-NetIPAddress against an Array

Tags: powershell

Good morning, I'm hoping this is an easy one;
I'm trying to get a Table to show in the terminal using `Get-NetIPAddress` against an array of Servers. I can get the table, but it either makes a new table for each item or only holds the last object and I'd like to make it one full table. below is the code I have

```
$Servers = @(Test1,Test2)

foreach($Server in $Servers){
  $GetIP = get-netipaddress -CimSession $Server -AddressFamily ipv4 -PrefixOrigin Manual | Select PSComputerName,IPAddress
  $GetIP | Format-Table
}
```

Comment: Actually it is an easy one. Remove `$GetIP = ` from the first line of code in your loop and remove the second line of code from your loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ForEach-Object` to construct a single pipeline that outputs to `Format-Table`:

```
$Servers |ForEach-Object {
  Get-NetIPAddress -CimSession $_ -AddressFamily ipv4 -PrefixOrigin Manual
} |Format-Table PSComputerName,IPAddress
```

As long as `Format-Table` is expecting more input from the upstream cmdlet, it'll just continue populating the same table.

---

Alternatively, use the `-HideTableHeaders` parameter to suppress repeated headers - only problem is you need the first invocation to actually include the table headers, but you could do something like:

```
# We'll use this hashtable to control the table header visibility
$FTParams = @{ HideTableHeaders = $false }

foreach($Server in $Servers){
  $GetIP = get-netipaddress -CimSession $Server -AddressFamily ipv4 -PrefixOrigin Manual | Select PSComputerName,IPAddress
  $GetIP | Format-Table @FTParams

  # Format-Table has run at least once, we can start hiding the headers
  $FTParams['HideTableHeaders'] = $true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are outputting the table *within* the foreach scriptblock, so `Format-Table` will naturally be creating a new table on each call.

The best option is to use piping as in Mathias answer. Send *all* objects in one stream to Format-Table.

But if you like to spell the process out for better understanding, build an array and then use it when finished.

```
$Servers = @(Test1,Test2)

[array]$result = $null

foreach($Server in $Servers){
  $result += Get-NetIpAddress -CimSession $Server -AddressFamily ipv4 -PrefixOrigin Manual | Select PSComputerName,IPAddress
}

$result | Format-Table
```